# Problem looping on SQL Server Execute Query on Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I need to create an excel starting from a SQL view and send it to some colleagues.

I've a big issue (I've almost spent all the afternoon) trying to fix it.

This is the main workflow

[image]

This is the definition of the ExecuteQuery item

[image]

The foreach definition

[image]

And then the Add Row item..

[image]

Apart the main problem of filling the data...my issue is that in the output I got only 1 row and not the numner of items in the query, that today are 21.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to do? do you want to send the sql query output into table?

Comment: Yes to an excel... but I think I have managed.. there was an issue since I need to take the element in position 0 from the body of parsed json

Comment: Posted an answer check that @advapi

Comment: You don't need a parse JSON given a way without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`Then:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**`Codeview:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Create_table": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "ColumnsNames": "UserID,FirstName,lastName,Email",
                        "Range": "A68",
                        "TableName": "rithtable98"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['excelonlinebusiness']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/drives/@{encodeURIComponent('b!JoFcxxFwI0t7KNUFbzrhrTp-pyVuAaka3')}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('01PEU3HOJLNA4B3APU'))}/tables",
                    "queries": {
                        "source": "me"
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "01PEUWZIGVMO35BOGASFA3HOJLNA4B3APU": "/Book1.xlsx"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "query": "SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM [dbo].[Users]"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/query/sql"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Add_a_row_into_a_table": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": "@items('For_each')",
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['excelonlinebusiness']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "post",
                            "path": "/codeless/v1.2/drives/@{encodeURIComponent('b!JoFcxxFwI0uYrGe8XWExB9Td3BfSC9dMpVU-Ps3B0t7KNUFbzrhrTp-pyVuAaka3')}/items/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('01PEUWZIGVMO35BOGASFA3HOJLNA4B3APU'))}/workbook/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(body('Create_table')?['title'])}/rows",
                            "queries": {
                                "source": "me"
                            }
                        },
                        "metadata": {
                            "01PEUWZIGVMO35BOGASFA3HOJLNA4B3APU": "/Book1.xlsx"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "ApiConnection"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')?['resultsets']?['Table1']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Create_table": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "excelonlinebusiness": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/resourceGroups/vrbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/excelonlinebusiness",
                    "connectionName": "excelonlinebusiness",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/excelonlinebusiness"
                },
                "sql": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed/resourceGroups/vrbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql",
                    "connectionName": "sql",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```